# How to make a model to consume data from API with retrovit

Tags: android, json

How to create a model for a case like this API output
[image: API Output]

I already created my model like

```
package com.bertho.tdashboard.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Visitor {

    @SerializedName("nb_uniq_visitors")
    @Expose
    private Integer nbUniqVisitors;
    @SerializedName("nb_users")
    @Expose
    private Integer nbUsers;
    @SerializedName("nb_visits")
    @Expose
    private Integer nbVisits;
    @SerializedName("nb_actions")
    @Expose
    private Integer nbActions;
    @SerializedName("nb_visits_converted")
    @Expose
    private Integer nbVisitsConverted;
    @SerializedName("bounce_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer bounceCount;
    @SerializedName("sum_visit_length")
    @Expose
    private Integer sumVisitLength;
    @SerializedName("max_actions")
    @Expose
    private Integer maxActions;
    @SerializedName("bounce_rate")
    @Expose
    private String bounceRate;
    @SerializedName("nb_actions_per_visit")
    @Expose
    private Double nbActionsPerVisit;
    @SerializedName("avg_time_on_site")
    @Expose
    private Integer avgTimeOnSite;

    /**
     * @return The nbUniqVisitors
     */
    public Integer getNbUniqVisitors() {
        return nbUniqVisitors;
    }

    /**
     * @param nbUniqVisitors The nb_uniq_visitors
     */
    public void setNbUniqVisitors(Integer nbUniqVisitors) {
        this.nbUniqVisitors = nbUniqVisitors;
    }

    /**
     * @return The nbUsers
     */
    public Integer getNbUsers() {
        return nbUsers;
    }

    /**
     * @param nbUsers The nb_users
     */
    public void setNbUsers(Integer nbUsers) {
        this.nbUsers = nbUsers;
    }

    /**
     * @return The nbVisits
     */
    public Integer getNbVisits() {
        return nbVisits;
    }

    /**
     * @param nbVisits The nb_visits
     */
    public void setNbVisits(Integer nbVisits) {
        this.nbVisits = nbVisits;
    }

    /**
     * @return The nbActions
     */
    public Integer getNbActions() {
        return nbActions;
    }

    /**
     * @param nbActions The nb_actions
     */
    public void setNbActions(Integer nbActions) {
        this.nbActions = nbActions;
    }

    /**
     * @return The nbVisitsConverted
     */
    public Integer getNbVisitsConverted() {
        return nbVisitsConverted;
    }

    /**
     * @param nbVisitsConverted The nb_visits_converted
     */
    public void setNbVisitsConverted(Integer nbVisitsConverted) {
        this.nbVisitsConverted = nbVisitsConverted;
    }

    /**
     * @return The bounceCount
     */
    public Integer getBounceCount() {
        return bounceCount;
    }

    /**
     * @param bounceCount The bounce_count
     */
    public void setBounceCount(Integer bounceCount) {
        this.bounceCount = bounceCount;
    }

    /**
     * @return The sumVisitLength
     */
    public Integer getSumVisitLength() {
        return sumVisitLength;
    }

    /**
     * @param sumVisitLength The sum_visit_length
     */
    public void setSumVisitLength(Integer sumVisitLength) {
        this.sumVisitLength = sumVisitLength;
    }

    /**
     * @return The maxActions
     */
    public Integer getMaxActions() {
        return maxActions;
    }

    /**
     * @param maxActions The max_actions
     */
    public void setMaxActions(Integer maxActions) {
        this.maxActions = maxActions;
    }

    /**
     * @return The bounceRate
     */
    public String getBounceRate() {
        return bounceRate;
    }

    /**
     * @param bounceRate The bounce_rate
     */
    public void setBounceRate(String bounceRate) {
        this.bounceRate = bounceRate;
    }

    /**
     * @return The nbActionsPerVisit
     */
    public Double getNbActionsPerVisit() {
        return nbActionsPerVisit;
    }

    /**
     * @param nbActionsPerVisit The nb_actions_per_visit
     */
    public void setNbActionsPerVisit(Double nbActionsPerVisit) {
        this.nbActionsPerVisit = nbActionsPerVisit;
    }

    /**
     * @return The avgTimeOnSite
     */
    public Integer getAvgTimeOnSite() {
        return avgTimeOnSite;
    }

    /**
     * @param avgTimeOnSite The avg_time_on_site
     */
    public void setAvgTimeOnSite(Integer avgTimeOnSite) {
        this.avgTimeOnSite = avgTimeOnSite;
    }

}
```

And My Response

```
package com.bertho.tdashboard.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class VisitorResponse {

    private List<Visitor> visitors;

    public List<Visitor> getVisitors() {
        return visitors;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Visitor> visitors) {
        this.visitors = visitors;
    }

}
```

But every time I tried to call the API, the results I get are always `null`. Is there something wrong with the model and the response that I have made?

How do I read the date data and the details to be retrieved and displayed to the screen.

Is the API format above can be made a model or whether it should change this API format?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Activity Code :

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ServiceCallBack {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BaseRequest baseRequest = new BaseRequest(MainActivity.this);
    baseRequest.setServiceCallBack(MainActivity.this);
    baseRequest.setRequestTag(RestClient.LOGIN_SERVICE_TAG);

    Api api = (Api) baseRequest.execute(Api.class);
    if (api != null) {
        api.getData(baseRequest.requestCallback());
    }
}

@Override
public void onSuccess(int tag, String baseResponse) {
    Log.e("onSuccess", "onSuccess" + baseResponse.toString());
}

@Override
public void onFail(RetrofitError error) {
    Log.e("onFail", "onFail" + error.toString());
}
```

}

2. Api Interface :

   public interface Api {

   @GET("/testing")
   public void getData(Callback callback);

}

```
3. Base Request :

public class BaseRequest {
private int requestTag;
private boolean progressShow = true;
private ServiceCallBack serviceCallBack;
private RestClient restClient;
private Context context;
private Callback<Object> callback;

public BaseRequest(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    setProgressShow(true);
}

public Object execute(Class classes){
        restClient=  new RestClient(context,this);
        return restClient.execute(classes);
}

public Callback<String> requestCallback(){

    return restClient.callback;
}
public Callback<Object> getCallback() {
    return callback;
}

public void setCallback(Callback<Object> callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

public RestClient getRestClient() {
    return restClient;
}

public void setRestClient(RestClient restClient) {
    this.restClient = restClient;
}

public ServiceCallBack getServiceCallBack() {
    return serviceCallBack;
}

public void setServiceCallBack(ServiceCallBack serviceCallBack) {
    this.serviceCallBack = serviceCallBack;
}

public int getRequestTag() {
    return requestTag;
}

public void setRequestTag(int requestType) {
    this.requestTag = requestType;
}

public boolean isProgressShow() {
    return progressShow;
}

public void setProgressShow(boolean progressShow) {
    this.progressShow = progressShow;
}
```

}

```
4. Service CallBack Interface :

public interface ServiceCallBack{
public void onSuccess(int tag, String baseResponse);
public void onFail(RetrofitError error);
}

5. RestClient :

public class RestClient {

public static String BASE_URL = "http://www.berthojoris.com/";

public static int LOGIN_SERVICE_TAG = 1001;


private BaseRequest baseRequest;
private ProgressDialog pDialog = null;
private Context context;

public RestClient(Context context, BaseRequest _baseRequest) {
    this.baseRequest = _baseRequest;
    this.context = context;
}

public Object execute(Class classes) {
    if (baseRequest.isProgressShow())
        showProgressDialog(context);
    return setUpRestClient(classes);
}

private Object setUpRestClient(Class apiClasses) {

    final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
            .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient));
    builder.setConverter(new StringConverter());
    RestAdapter restAdapter = builder.build();
    return restAdapter.create(apiClasses);

}

public Callback<String> callback = new Callback<String>() {

    @Override
    public void success(String o, Response response) {
        if (o != null && !o.isEmpty())
        baseRequest.getServiceCallBack().onSuccess(baseRequest.getRequestTag(), o);
        dismissProgressDialog();

    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        baseRequest.getServiceCallBack().onFail(error);
        dismissProgressDialog();
    }
};

public void showProgressDialog(Context context) {
    try {
        if (((Activity) context).isFinishing()) {
            return;
        }
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void dismissProgressDialog() {
    try {
        if (pDialog != null)
            pDialog.dismiss();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


class StringConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object fromBody(TypedInput typedInput, Type type) throws ConversionException {
        String text = null;
        try {

            text = fromStream(typedInput.in());
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
            ignored.printStackTrace();
        }
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public TypedOutput toBody(Object o) {

        return null;
    }

    private String fromStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line);
            out.append(newLine);
        }
        return out.toString();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: When I try to add your code, I got some error code...whats your version retrovit? And any extra code I see in your suggest code...Actualy another module with another API have done with common retrovit example code in internet

Comment: add these three gradles


 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0'

Comment: I create sample and done these and get response then i gave you these all classes code... So I am 100% sure about the response.. Please check, actually this vote down waste all of my help so i say you to check this is helpful or not for you ...

Comment: I use retrovit 2. Hmmm...can I add two version in one project? Maybe I must add okhttp lib in my gradle

Comment: Can you convert to v2 style? Like my fragment code, I try to consume API from my server with v2 style

Comment: What do you mean by v2 style? and implements same interface in fragment then it will give you response in fragment also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116985/discussion-between-chirag-arora-and-bertho-joris).

Comment: means use of Reactive-X to get response. Right?

Comment: Maybe chat the best solution, but my english not good :) if ok, leets go

Answer (score -1):

If you use @Expose on a field you're telling Gson to include that property into your JSON String. All the fields that arn't annotated with the @Expose will be excluded

Use only @SerializedName() and check below link :

[Gson Serialization](http://camelcode.org/tutorial/Exclude-fields-from-JSON-using-Gson-with-@Expose.htm)

Comment: You mean I must remove all `@Expose` Annotation?

Comment: Yes please try without @Expose

Comment: Hi @Chirag Arora when I try debug, I get some error. Emulator stop inside `onFailure` block. Please see : https://s31.postimg.org/kx3zn4jcb/error.png

Comment: Please check your response status code here i think its give internet connection error, Please check internet connects properly or not or you added internet permission in manifest.

Comment: `onFailure` is gone... But still the same output. Null. Please see https://s31.postimg.org/wlgf0vud7/error.png

Comment: Please share your Service calling code.. Problem in that not in POJO class. Please check first your webservice calling through Postman or rest-client

Comment: My testing API service : http://www.berthojoris.com/testing/
|
My fragment : http://pastebin.com/kwsUywR9
|
My API Client : http://pastebin.com/SJRwnUnH
|
My Interface : http://pastebin.com/pkKLj2gy

Comment: Thanks for your help @Chirag

Comment: Please check new answer and in main activity override method on success you get response and then use according to your POJO classes.

Comment: With the new (and much more elaborate) answer in place there really is no point in keeping this one, right? So, feel free to delete this post.